# Accessing ssh with Process.Start ()

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, openssh

I have a batch file which starts a ssh command. It uses the OpenSSH client included in Windows 10 (c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe) If I double click the batch file in the explorer, it works fine. If I run it from a cmd.exe window, it works fine too. But it doesn't find the ssh.exe if I run it from a C# application using

```
Process process = new Process ();
process.StartInfo.FileName = string_to_batch_file;
process.Start ();
```

The source of the problem is the invisibility of the "OpenSSH" directory below System32 if I start it from the C# application. If I put

```
dir c:\Windows\System32\
pause
```

in the batch file and start it from the explorer, the "OpenSSH" directory is visible. If I start it from the C# application, it isn't.

What's the reason for this behavior and what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mofi, it's a 32 bit/64 bit problem. I haven't thought on that before. I just switched my C# application to 64 bit.